# Priority Queue in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, queue

I am working with a real-time object detection on one of my edge evaluation boards and have a doubt
regarding the usage of the priority queue in the C++ application code

Scenario:

I am using multiple threads (say 4) for reading(1), object detection(2), and displaying tasks(1). For reference, I am following the code available here [object detection on multiple threads](https://github.com/Xilinx/Vitis-AI/blob/master/mpsoc/vitis_ai_dnndk_samples/video_analysis/src/main.cc). In the code, I didn't understand how the priority queue for the display task is defined. Here is the code sample,

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
// comparison algorithm for priority_queue

class Compare {
    public:
    bool operator()(const pair<int, Mat> &n1, const pair<int, Mat> &n2) const {
        return n1.first > n2.first;
    }
};

queue<pair<int, Mat>> read_queue;                                               // read queue
priority_queue<pair<int, Mat>, vector<pair<int, Mat>>, Compare> display_queue;  // display queue
```

I don't get it the usage of class compare and etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what exactly dont you understand about it?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/what-are-c-functors-and-their-uses for what `Compare` is.